# New questions don't appear in Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Normally I see a notification that (N) new questions have appeared and click on the notification, this normally refreshes and updates the page with the new questions.

[image]

As of today (worked fine yesterday), it now quickly displays and then doesn't update

[image]

or sometimes does update in a weird way (i.e. suddenly flashes 1 new question and then another) appears to be OK and then on the next new question notification suddenly reverts to some cached state from minutes ago.

I'm using Chrome version: `46.0.2490.86 m (64-bit)` on Windows 7 64-bit

Also doesn't work on FireFox 42.0

Comment: Was typing the same question. Tested it in FF also, It ain't workin

Comment: I observe the same or it suddenly flashes several updates at once and 3 new questions appear but worse is that is reverts to some previous cached state sometimes

Comment: Turns out notifications are still faulty. They were the reason I disabled the new navigation several weeks ago...

Comment: @vaultah it was all working fine yesterday (for me at least)

Comment: I think this is happening for me on meta as well.  Just started today (also Chrome 46 Windows 7).

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour. It was fine this morning. This behaviour seems to have started within the last 2-3 hours. Also for me (On Chrome 46 for OSX) the right side bar (containing the Blog links and Favourite Tags) sometimes disappears along with the new questions.

Comment: Yup, seeing this too, worked a few hours ago, now all very broken. Most irritating.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed in build `#3920` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3025` (stackoverflow.com).

---

For the curious: it was *caching*.

Clicking on the "n new questions" box displayed the new questions, but then a spurious async load was fired. This hit our tag engine which caches question lists and thus it would not have the new question. Hence, the new question was deleted.

Comment: \o/ And there was much rejoicing.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy fix all is well..